# Set custom color to UITabBarItem not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to change the selected text color of a TabBarItem.

If I use:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor()], forState: .Selected)
```

It works...

But if I use:

```
let darkColor = UIColor(red: 44, green: 62, blue: 80, alpha: 1)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : darkColor], forState: .Selected)
```

It does not work.

Is there any other option to change the selected text color to any color I want?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIColor` initializer you are using accepts values from 0.0 to 1.0 range - you simply need to map them from 0 - 255 range you were using.

This should work :

```
UIColor(red: 44.0/255.0, green: 62.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Related [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:)